# Find an inverse function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, inverse

this is probably a silly question, but how do I find an inverse function of y$ = a - b \cdot \text{ln}(1-\frac{x}{c})$? I tried doing $\text{exp()}$ on both sides but I don't know how to cope with $\text{exp}(b\cdot\text{ln}())$. Is there a simple trick I forgot about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Reduce[y == a - b*Log[1 - x/c], x, Reals]
```

> `(b == 0 &&  y == a && ((c < 0 && x > c) || (c > 0 && x < c))) || (b != 0 &&  c != 0 && x == c - c E^((a - y)/b))`

```
Solve[y == a - b*Log[1 - x/c], x, Reals]
```

> `{{x -> c - c E^((a - y)/b)}}`

```
InverseFunction[a - b*Log[1 - #/c] &]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[-(c*(-1 + E^((a - #1)/b))),  Inequality[-Pi, Less, Im[(a - #1)/b], LessEqual, Pi]] &`